# Microsoft Graph Rest API v1.0 --- HTTP GET Request

Tags: http, search, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to make a request like shown below
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#code-try-15)
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsOVs.png)

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iygnH.png)

Tried to see if it works on their graph explorer ---> https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
I need specifically to make this request work ---> **[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$search="displayName:wa"](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$search=%22displayName:wa%22)**

But as you see I get this error which suggests that I didn't add the consistencyLevel header but I did, in multiple ways. It's annoying :))

============================================
Update:
I logged in my student microsoft account and now I got this
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0L6p.png)

Comment: If you add the api permission in azure ad app? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the "?" in the url

[image]

====================Update====================

It can work, but you need to send request with a correct access token. I'm afraid it met some issue when test in the self-contained test tool.

[image]

Comment: I'm confused ---> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$search="displayName:wa". Isn't here a "?" ?

Comment: I am looking forward to specifically this query ---> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$search="displayName:wa"

Comment: You may test it in tools like postman. @MarcianBondoc

Comment: I got what I was looking for anyway, thank man! You are amazing!!! <3 :)))

Comment: It seems worked, congratulations anyway : )